# Aggregation to calculate number of each tag, where there are two types of tags

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with elements that can be simplified to this:

```
{
  t1 : [1, 3, 6],
  t2 : [8, 9]
}
```

were in `t1` and `t2` can be from 1 to 10 positive integers without duplicates. I need to calculate how many each of these numbers are there in t1 and t2 in all documents in collections.

For example if my collection consists of 3 documents:

```
{
  t1 : [1, 3, 6],
  t2 : [8, 9]
}, {
  t1 : [1, 2],
  t2 : [8]
}, {
  t1 : [6],
  t2 : [8, 1]
}
```

I should have something like

```
t1 : {
   1 : 2,   // there are 2 elements of 1 in t1
   3 : 1,   // there is 1 element of 3 in t1
   6 : 2,
   2 : 1
}

t2 : {
  8 : 3,    // there are 3 elements of 8 in t2
  9 : 1,
  1 : 1
}
```

What I am currently doing is something like this:

```
var t1 = {}, t2 = {};
db.coll.find().forEach(function(e){
   // where I am iterating through each element in t1 and t2 to
   // and increase/populate values in t1 and t2
})
```

Although there is nothing wrong in this approach, I think that there is a better way with aggregation framework. Is it possible to do so using aggregation only once?

**P.S.** the output I showed in the example is just an example. Any output that can give me information I need is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single form for aggregate:

```js
db.tags.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "t1": 1,
        "t2": 2,
        "type": { "$literal": ["t1","t2"] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$project": {
        "type": 1,
        "value": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$type", "t1" ] },
                "$t1",
                "$t2"
            ]
        } 
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$value" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "type": "$type",
            "value": "$value"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id.type": 1, "_id.value": 1 } }
])
```

And output:

```js
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t1", "value" : 1 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t1", "value" : 2 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t1", "value" : 3 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t1", "value" : 6 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t2", "value" : 1 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t2", "value" : 8 }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "t2", "value" : 9 }, "count" : 1 }
```

Or if you prefer a single document just replace the end stage with a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "t1": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "t1" ] },
                    { "value": "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "t2": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "t2" ] },
                    { "value": "$_id.value", "count": "$count" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "t1": { "$setDifference": [ "$t1", [false] ] },
        "t2": { "$setDifference": [ "$t2", [false] ] }
    }}
```

And the result:

```js
{ 
    "t1" : [ 
        { "value" : 2, "count" : 1 }, 
        { "value" : 6, "count" : 2 }, 
        { "value" : 3, "count" : 1 }, 
        { "value" : 1, "count" : 2 } 
    ], 
    "t2" : [ 
        { "value" : 1, "count" : 1 },
        { "value" : 9, "count" : 1 },
        { "value" : 8, "count" : 3 } 
    ] 
}
```

These are possible without using the new operators from MongoDB 2.6, it just takes a bit more work.

---

The mapReduce way seems fairly straightforward. The output is not in your format of course because of the constraints of mapReduce, but it gets the result without iterating queries:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
      delete this["_id"];

      for ( var k in this ) {
        var list = this[k];
        list.forEach(function(v) {
          emit( { k: k , v: v }, 1 );
        });
      }
    },
    function (key,values) {
      return values.length;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

And the output would be:

```js
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t1", "v" : 1 }, "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t1", "v" : 2 }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t1", "v" : 3 }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t1", "v" : 6 }, "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t2", "v" : 1 }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t2", "v" : 8 }, "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "k" : "t2", "v" : 9 }, "value" : 1 }
```

Also depends if you need to flexible on the "key" names.

Comment: Thank you. The output does not make any difference to me. I did not got your last sentence about flexible key names.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Finally woke up. I was thinking down the wrong track, but the aggregate answer is there now as well

Answer (score 1):

```
db.nr.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$t1" }, { $group: { '_id': '$t1','count' : { '$sum':1 } } }, {    $project : {_id: 0, t1: '$_id', count:1}}, { $sort: { t1:1 } } ])
"count" : 2, "t1" : 1 }
"count" : 1, "t1" : 2 }
"count" : 1, "t1" : 3 }
"count" : 2, "t1" : 6 }

db.nr.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$t2" }, { $group: { '_id': '$t2','count' : { '$sum':1 } } }, { $project : { _id: 0, t2: '$_id', count:1 } }, { $sort: { t2:1 } } ])
"count" : 1, "t2" : 1 }
"count" : 3, "t2" : 8 }
"count" : 1, "t2" : 9 }
```

### SQL

To see how this could be done in SQL, check out the following queries.

To count the values of `t1`:

```
select
    t1 as "value",
    count(*) as "count"
from (
    select unnest(e.t1) as t1
    from event e
) t1
group by t1
order by t1
```

And, we get:

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |

And for `t2`:

```
select
    t2 as "value",
    count(*) as "count"
from (
    select unnest(e.t2) as t2
    from event e
) t2
group by t2
order by t2
```

And, we get the right result:

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 |

Or, if you want to get them all in a single query:

```
with array_unnest as (
    select unnest(e.t1) as t1,
           unnest(e.t2) as t2
    from event e
),
t1_count as (
    select
        't1' as src,
        t1 as "value",
        count(*) over (partition by t1) as "count"
    from array_unnest
    where t1 is not null
),
t2_count as (
     select
         't2' as src,
         t2 as "value",
         count(*) over (partition by t2) as "count"
     from array_unnest
     where t2 is not null
)
select distinct *
from (
     select *
     from t1_count
     union all
     select *
     from t2_count
) t_u
order by src, "value"
```

Or, even aggregated as JSON:

```
select
    src,
    json_agg(t_c)
from (
         select
             't1'        as src,
             to_json(t1) as t_c
         from (
                  select t1_v as value, count(*) as "count"
                  from (
                           select unnest(e.t1) as t1_v
                           from event e
                       ) t1_a
                  group by t1_v
              ) t1
         union all
         select
             't2'        as src,
             to_json(t2) as t_c
         from (
                  select t2_v as value, count(*) as "count"
                  from (
                           select unnest(e.t2) as t2_v
                           from event e
                       ) t2_a
                  group by t2_v
              ) t2
     ) t_agg
group by src
order by src
```

And, you get the expected result:

| src | json_agg |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | [{"value":3,"count":1}, {"value":6,"count":2}, {"value":2,"count":1}, {"value":1,"count":2}] |
| t2 | [{"value":9,"count":1}, {"value":1,"count":1}, {"value":8,"count":3}] |

```
                  |
```

That's why I use SQL over MongoDB.

Comment: thank you. But I am not really sure that this would be better then my foreach statement (because here there will be two scans). And this is exactly why I told that I am looking to use aggregation once. Please take my +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Unfortunately, unwinding both t1 and t2 will end-up with a Cartesian product, so counting independently is not a trivial thing with a single aggregation query.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Not if you combine them into the same field. See my answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn Very ingenious solution. Usually I'd use an extra business key field to group back the double unwounded pipe, and I would never thought adding a literal as you did. Very clever!